# Check for existing DSN before creating it with vb6 code

Tags: vb6

i have done a connection using DSN, in which i have created a DSN throgh program. In that i have called a function to create a DSN, I dont want to call that function ecerytime i run the software, Instead i want to check whether dsn with the same name is already exist in the system or not, if it is not exist then only call to the function`

```
Public Sub ConnectDB(Con As ADODB.Connection)

Call CreatSQLDSN("TRDSN", VarSrvNm, VarDbName)
If Cn.State = 1 Then Cn.Close
On Error Resume Next
Con.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Data Source=TRDSN;Initial Catalog='" & VarDbName & "'"

Con.Open Con.ConnectionString
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
If Err.Number = -2147467259 Then
    If MsgBox(ServerName & " Server not Found. Connect to Other Server?", vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2 + vbYesNo, "") = vbYes Then
        PrintFile = Trim(Left(FindWindowPath, 3) & "DosPrint.Bat")
        FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile PrintFile, True
        Set TextStream = FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile(PrintFile, ForAppending)
        TextStream.WriteLine "Del " & Left(FindWindowPath, 3) & "ServerName.dat"
        TextStream.Close
        Shell PrintFile, vbHide
    End If
    End
Else
If MsgBox(Err.Description, vbQuestion + vbOKOnly, "") = vbOK Then
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
End If
0
End Sub

Public Function CreatSQLDSN(SqlDsnName As String, SqlServerName As String, SqlDataName As String)
Dim Ret%, Driver$, Attributes$
Driver = "SQL Server" & Chr(0)
Attributes = "Server=" & SqlServerName & Chr(0)
Attributes = Attributes & "DSN=" & SqlDsnName & Chr(0)
Attributes = Attributes & "Database=" & SqlDataName & Chr(0)
Ret = SQLConfigDataSource(vbAPINull, ODBC_Add_User_DSN, Driver, Attributes)

'ret is equal to 1 on success and 0 if there is an error
If Ret <> 1 Then
    MsgBox "User DSN Creation Failed"
End If
End Function`
```

Comment: I can't help you, but you might try including other, better targeted tags such as, perhaps, sql-server where you can find people with experience in this sort of thing.

Comment: I did a little searching and many people check the Registry to see if the DSN exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of options come to mind when needing to know if a DSN exists.  You could either read through the Registry, or leverage your existing API call.  I prefer the second option.  It seems like a cleaner way to check for the existence of the DSN.  Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SQLConfigDataSource Lib "ODBCCP32.DLL" (ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal fRequest As Long, ByVal lpszDriver As String, ByVal lpszAttributes As String) As Long

Private Const ODBC_ADD_DSN = 1
Private Const ODBC_CONFIG_DSN = 2
Private Const ODBC_REMOVE_DSN = 3
Private Const ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN = 4
Private Const ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN = 5
Private Const ODBC_REMOVE_SYS_DSN = 6
Private Const ODBC_REMOVE_DEFAULT_DSN = 7

Private Sub cmdCreate_Click()
   Dim VarSrvNm As String
   Dim VarDbName As String

   VarSrvNm = "MyServer"
   VarDbName = "MyDB"

   If Not SQLDSNExists("TRDSN", VarSrvNm, VarDbName) Then
      If Not CreateSQLDSN("TRDSN", VarSrvNm, VarDbName) Then
         MsgBox "User DSN Creation Failed"
      End If
   End If
End Sub

Public Function CreateSQLDSN(SqlDsnName As String, SqlServerName As String, SqlDataName As String) As Boolean
   Dim Ret%, Driver$, Attributes$

   Driver = "SQL Server" & Chr(0)
   Attributes = "Server=" & SqlServerName & Chr(0)
   Attributes = Attributes & "DSN=" & SqlDsnName & Chr(0)
   Attributes = Attributes & "Database=" & SqlDataName & Chr(0)

   Ret = SQLConfigDataSource(0&, ODBC_ADD_DSN, Driver, Attributes)

   'ret is equal to 1 on success and 0 if there is an error
   CreateSQLDSN = (Ret = 1)
End Function

Public Function SQLDSNExists(SqlDsnName As String, SqlServerName As String, SqlDataName As String) As Boolean
   Dim Ret%, Driver$, Attributes$

   Driver = "SQL Server" & Chr(0)
   Attributes = "Server=" & SqlServerName & Chr(0)
   Attributes = Attributes & "DSN=" & SqlDsnName & Chr(0)
   Attributes = Attributes & "Database=" & SqlDataName & Chr(0)

   Ret = SQLConfigDataSource(0&, ODBC_CONFIG_DSN, Driver, Attributes)

   'ret is equal to 1 on success and 0 if there is an error
   SQLDSNExists = (Ret = 1)
End Function
```

The main idea here is to try to modify the DSN you want to add.  If the call fails, then the DSN does not exist.

Comment: Thank you  @brian ,this exactly what i was looking for, I did checked it with register key but that just checks whether the dsn exists or not and it doesnt configure it, can i use the same configure methor with that too ?